# Selenium/JUnit, NullPointerException with a findBy annotation

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I create a Java project for training with Selenium and JUnit. A first test connect the user to the website, the second test check an information in the homepage when the user is connected. I don't understand why my second test begin and stop with a NullPointerException...

I use this files :

A main files => for declare a JunitCore and run two class test (via jCore.run(test1.class, test2.class)

main :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JUnitCore jCore = new JUnitCore();
        //jCore.addListener(new ExecutionListener());
        jCore.run(WebsiteLoginTest.class, WebsiteCheckEventTest.class);
    }
}
```

Two tests class files :

test1.java :

```
public class Test1 {
    @Test
    public void testlogin(){
        WebsiteHomePage homePage = new WebsiteHomePage().open();        
        homePage.login(...);
    }
}
```

test2.java :

```
public class WebsiteCheckEventTest {

    @Test
    public void websiteCheckEvent(){
        System.out.println("a");
        WebsiteHomePageConnected homePageConnected = new WebsiteHomePageConnected();
        System.out.println("b");
        homePageConnected.checkEvent();
        System.out.println("c");
    }
}
```

And two "page" files : (use page object pattern)

WebsiteHomePage (no logged) :

```
public class WebsiteHomePage extends WebsitePage<WebsiteHomePage> {
    @FindBy(id = "usernameLogin")   WebElement usernameInputText;
    @FindBy(id = "passwordLogin")   WebElement passwordInputText;
    @FindBy(id = "loginSubmit")     WebElement loginInputSubmit; 

    @Override
    public ExpectedCondition getPageLoadCondition() {
        return ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Homepage");
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageUrl() {
        return "";
    }

    public void login(String univers, String login, String password){
        usernameInputText.sendKeys(login);
        passwordInputText.sendKeys(password);
        loginInputSubmit.click();
    }

    public WebsiteHomePage open() {
        return new WebsiteHomePage().openPage(WebsiteHomePage.class);
    }

}
```

WebsiteHomePageConnected (when the user is connected via the first test) :

```
public class WebsiteHomePageConnected extends WebsitePage<WebsiteHomePageConnected> {

    @FindBy(id = "playerName")       WebElement playerNameLi;
    @FindBy(id = "eventContent")     WebElement eventContentDiv;
    @FindBy(id = "eventListWrap")    WebElement eventListDiv; 

    @Override
    public ExpectedCondition getPageLoadCondition() {
        return  ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(playerNameLi);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageUrl() {
        return "";
    }

    public void checkEvent(String event){
        System.out.println("111"); // is displayed in the console
        eventContentDiv.click();
        System.out.println("222"); // isn't displayed in the console
    }
}
```

When I run the program, the console shows : 
    a
    b
    c
    111

...but no 222, the program stop in the WebsiteHomePageConnected file in the line with "eventContentDiv.click()" without any error message.

In the main file, if I uncomment //jCore.addListener(new ExecutionListener()) the console show :

```
a
b
c
111
Execution of test case failed : java.lang.NullPointerException
    at page.WebsiteHomePageConnected.checkEvent(WebsiteHomePageConnected.java:34)
    at test.WebsiteCheckEventTest.websiteCheckEvent(WebsiteCheckEventTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:105)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:94)
    at Main.main(Main.java:32)
```

So, the "eventContentDiv" seems be the problem, but when I check manually the website, after connection, I find the div with the id "eventContent" (via firebug ctrl+f). Manually, More precisely :

1. I go to the homepage website
2. I enter log and password, I submit
3. Im redirected to the homepage connected (the url is a little different)
4. I open firebug, press ctrl+f, search "eventContent" and I find the element

So...why my program doesn't find this element ?

~UPDATE~
This is the abstract websitePage Class :

```
public abstract class WebsitePage<T>{


    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.test.com/";
    public T openPage(Class<T> pageObject){

        T page = PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), pageObject);
        getDriver().get(BASE_URL + getPageUrl());

        ExpectedCondition pageLoadCondition = ((WebsitePage) page).getPageLoadCondition();    
        WaitForPageToLoad(pageLoadCondition);

        return page;

    }

    private static final int LOAD_TIMEOUT = 30;
    private static final int REFRESH_RATE = 2;
    private void WaitForPageToLoad(ExpectedCondition pageLoadCondition) {
        Wait wait = new FluentWait(getDriver())
                        .withTimeout(LOAD_TIMEOUT,  TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .pollingEvery(REFRESH_RATE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public abstract ExpectedCondition getPageLoadCondition();
    public abstract String getPageUrl();
}
```

~UPDATE 2~
Ive made a mistake in my com in the public class WebsiteHomePageConnected. Change :

```
...
System.out.println("222"); // is displayed in the console
...
```

to

```
...
System.out.println("222"); // isn't displayed in the console
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the flow of your program... Did you include everything? Because I can't see how WebsiteHomePageConnected can represent a connected page.

Comment: I add the WebsitePage class =) there is (almost) all my code. I include anything else

Comment: Did it work when U use driver.findElement(By...  ??

Comment: I use annotations (@FindBy(...)). As you can see, in the first class (test1), there are annotations and the test1 goes smoothly. But when the test2 begin, I get a NullPointerException with the WebElement eventContentDiv.

Comment: Ok, I've got two ideas. First - can you confirm there is no element with id "playerName" on the logging page? Second - would anything happen (would the program run at all) if you changed ConnectedPage condition to "eventContent"?

Comment: Thanks for your help =) First : I confirm (nothing when I firebug and ctrl+f in the not connected homepage). Second : I change ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(playerNameLi) to ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(eventContentDiv) and...I get the same output x) its crazy !